# Doing rank-n quantification in Idris

Tags: dependent-type, higher-rank-types, idris

I can only do rank-n types in Idris 0.9.12 in a rather clumsy way:

```
tupleId : ((a : Type) -> a -> a) -> (a, b) -> (a, b)
tupleId f (a, b) = (f _ a, f _ b)
```

I need the underscores wherever there's a type application, because Idris throws parse errors when I try to make the (nested) type arguments implicit:

```
tupleId : ({a : Type} -> a -> a) -> (a, b) -> (a, b) -- doesn't compile
```

A probably bigger issue is that I can't do class constraints in higher-rank types at all. I can't translate the following Haskell function to Idris:

```
appShow :: Show a => (forall a. Show a => a -> String) -> a -> String
appShow show x = show x
```

This also prevents me from using Idris functions as type synonyms for types such as `Lens`, which is `Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t` in Haskell.

Any way to remedy or circumvent the above issues?

Comment: It's on my TODO list - normally things move up the TODO list if somebody else asks about them, so just asking this is one way to help remedy it :). Surprisingly, there hasn't really been much demand for this, though obviously it would be nice.

There is some trickiness in getting implicit arguments right, so we've taken a pretty simple approach for now.

Type classes are first class, so there is also a clumsy way to do class constraints - treat them as normal function arguments, and use '%instance' to find the instance explicitly.

Comment: @EdwinBrady thanks, I accept this as an answer (or I'd do so were it an answer).

Comment: It doesn't yet feel like a proper answer... I'll get back to you soon hopefully!

Comment: Part 4 of my [question on the google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/idris-lang/VAbWdO2K9tQ/4dGxMAKBGk8J), is similar to this SO question, cross linking for future readers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've just implemented this in master, allowing implicits in arbitrary scopes, and it'll be in the next hackage release. It's not well tested yet though! I have at least tried the following simple examples, and a few others:

```
appShow : Show a => ({b : _} -> Show b => b -> String) -> a -> String
appShow s x = s x

AppendType : Type
AppendType = {a, n, m : _} -> Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (n + m) a

append : AppendType
append [] ys = ys
append (x :: xs) ys = x :: append xs ys

tupleId : ({a : _} -> a -> a) -> (a, b) -> (a, b)
tupleId f (a, b) = (f a, f b)

Proxy  : Type -> Type -> Type -> Type -> (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type

Producer' : Type -> (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type
Producer' a m t = {x', x : _} -> Proxy x' x () a m t

yield : Monad m => a -> Producer' a m ()
```

The main constraint at the minute is that you can't give values for implicit arguments directly, except at the top level. I'll do something about that eventually...

Comment: Are type classes going to happen too?